# how to find inverse of a matrix

Tags: determinant, adjoint-operators

How to find the inverse of a 4x4 order matrix using adjoints for example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -6 & -2 &  -3 \\  5 &-13 &-4 &-7 \\ -1 & 4&  1&  2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you not know what an adjoint is? Do you know what an adjoint is, but you don't know how to put them together to get the inverse? Give us a better idea of what help you need.

Answer (score 0):

The **adjoint** of a square matrix $A$ is the transpose of the cofactor matrix $C$.
The **minor** of the entry of $A$ in row $i$ column $j,$ denoted $M_{i,j}$ is the determinant of the submatrix formed by deleting the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.
Then, the $(i,j)$ entry of C is simply defined as $(-1)^{i+j}\cdot M_{i,j}$.

For the above matrix, you get the following cofactor matrix:
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 4 & 1 \\  -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 3 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Taking the transpose, you get the adjoint:
$$Adj(A)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\  -1 & 0 & -2 & 1 \\ 4 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & -2 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

To get $A^{-1}$ from $Adj(A)$ you have to scale by the (inverse of the) determinant of $A$. You don't actually need to explicitly compute $det(A)$ in this case since you can check that $Adj(A)\cdot A = -I$, so you see that it must be $det(A) = -1$, and $A^{-1}$ is just $Adj(A)$ with entries with opposite sign.